Find all tables that have a set of column in KDB
I have a list of column name. These are different columns that are in different tables in my environment. What i want to create is a dictionary which has key has column and value as list of table name that contains that column.
Is there an easy way to achieve it in KDB ?
I am trying to do something like below:-
 colDict:()!()
 CheckColInTables:{[tab;col] colPresent:0b; 
                   colPresent:(col in cols tab);
                   $[ colPresent & (not col in key colDict ); colDict[col]: enlist tab; colDict[col]:colDict[col],enlist ab]; :colDict; };

 GetColTabMapping:{[uniqueCols;tableList] 
                    { tab:x; colDict::CheckColInTables[tab;] each uniqueCols; } each tableList;
                  };

It seems that uniqueCols that i pass inside subfunction which calls CheckColInTables and updates colDict complains about not knowing uniqueCols. I tried to assign uniqueCols to a variable inside GetColTabMapping and then use that variable inside but that does not work either.

If you have a lambda inside a function then it's not going to have that parent functions variables in scope. You have to pass them through, aka your last line would be { tab:x; colDict::CheckColInTables[tab;] each y; }[;uniqueCols] each tableList. I haven't tested if this would actually work overall, just saying that this will solve your variable scoping problem

@terrylynch thanks a lot this resolves the unused variable error, but somewhere I am getting the type error. When I make the call to GetColTabMapping function.

There's a flaw in your handling of colDict I suspect. colDict is a global dictionary and you return it every time CheckColInTables is called. However that means that CheckColInTables[tab;] each uniqueCols returns it N times where N is the number of uniqueCols .... but then you're globally assigning that back to colDict. Now colDict isn't a dictionary is a list of N dictionaries. Then for the next table in tableList you're trying to look up colDict as if it's still a dictionary. Don't return colDict from CheckColInTables, just operate on it globally the whole time

@terrylynch your input was useful and right, modified it and got the desired results. Though I had to improve the logic and instead of using $ ( if else ) used a combination of if and $ ( if else ) while populating the dictionary.

You can simplify this down to:
q)t:([] a:1 2 3;b:4 5 6;c:7 8 9)
q)t1:([] b:1 2 3;c:4 5 6;d:7 8 9)

q){x!y where each x in/:\: cols each y}[`a`b`d`e;tables[]]
a| ,`t
b| `t`t1
d| ,`t1
e| `symbol$()

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/maps/#each-left-and-each-right
